# docker login fails with bad gateway. Potential V1 vs V2 issue?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I received a docker registry location to login to and pull some images from at my organization. On attempts to login, I receive the following error:

```
docker login -u test-user internal.server.com:8080/test
Password:
Error response from daemon: Get https://internal.server.com:8080/v2/: Bad Gateway
```

I turned debug on for the docker daemon and tried again and receive the following errors:

```
level=debug msg="attempting v2 login to registry endpoint https://internal.server.com:8080/v2/"
level=info msg="Error logging in to v2 endpoint, trying next endpoint: Get https://internal.server.com:8080/v2/: Bad Gateway"
level=debug msg="FIXME: Got an API for which error does not match any expected type!!!: Get https://internal.server.com:8080/v2/: Bad Gateway" error...l.Error" module=api
```

If I am interpreting the error correctly, this means the my docker client is attempting to access the registry at v2 yet the registry doesn't seem to support v2? Or do I have this backwards (or some other issue entirely)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`/v2` is part of the [registry API](https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec/blob/main/spec.md#endpoints). It will exist on all requests, so receiving a Bad Gateway from this indicates an error with the registry server.